# PHP Edit Toggle Open/Close Box

Tags: php, toggle, box

I am using Job Roller theme for wordpress.

I would like to make one small change.

If you see demo here: http://demos.appthemes.com/?theme=jobroller

Notice the "Job Category" link in right sidebar, clicking this will open the toggle box and display a list of categories.

I would like this list to be open by default when page loads.

Below is the code which displays Category Widget.

```
<li class="widget widget-nav">

<ul class="display_section">
<li><a href="#browseby" class="noscroll"><?php _e('Browse by&hellip;', APP_TD); ?></a>    </li>
<li><a href="#tags" class="noscroll"><?php _e('Tags', APP_TD); ?></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="browseby" class="tabbed_section"><div class="contents">
<ul>
    <?php
    // By Type
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'parent'             => 0,
        'hide_empty'         => (int)get_option('jr_show_empty_categories'),
    );
    $terms = get_terms( 'job_type', apply_filters('jr_nav_job_type', $args) );
    if ($terms) :
        echo '<li><a class="top" href="#open">'.__('Job Type', APP_TD).'</a> <ul>';

        foreach($terms as $term) :
            echo '<li class="page_item ';
            if ( isset($wp_query->queried_object->slug) && $wp_query->queried_object->slug==$term->slug ) echo 'current_page_item';
            echo '"><a href="'.get_term_link( $term->slug, 'job_type' ).'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
        endforeach;

        echo '</ul></li>';
    endif;

    // By Salary
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'parent'               => 0,
        'hide_empty'         => (int)get_option('jr_show_empty_categories')
    );
    $terms = get_terms( 'job_salary',  apply_filters('jr_nav_job_salary', $args) );
    if ($terms) :
        echo '<li><a class="top" href="#open">'.__('Job Salary', APP_TD).'</a> <ul>';

        foreach($terms as $term) :
            echo '<li class="page_item ';
            if ( isset($wp_query->queried_object->slug) &&     $wp_query->queried_object->slug==$term->slug ) echo 'current_page_item';
            echo '"><a href="'.get_term_link( $term->slug, 'job_salary' ).'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
        endforeach;

        echo '</ul></li>';
    endif;

    // By Cat
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'parent'             => 0,
        'hide_empty'         => (int)get_option('jr_show_empty_categories'),
    );
    $terms = get_terms( 'job_cat', apply_filters('jr_nav_job_cat', $args) );
    if ($terms) :
                echo '<li><a class="top" href="#open">'.__('Job Category',   APP_TD).'</a> <ul>';

                foreach($terms as $term):
                    echo '<li class="page_item ';
                    if ( isset($wp_query->queried_object->slug) &&   $wp_query->queried_object->slug==$term->slug ) echo 'current_page_item';
                    echo '"><a href="'.get_term_link( $term->slug, 'job_cat'   ).'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';

                    if ( ! $term->count ):
                         // echo terms childrens
                         $children = get_term_children($term->term_id, 'job_cat');
                         if ( is_array( $children ) ) foreach($children as $child):
                                $child_term = get_term_by('id', $child, 'job_cat');
                                echo '<li class="page_item page_item_children ';
                                if ( isset($wp_query->queried_object->slug) &&   $wp_query->queried_object->slug==$child_term->slug ) echo 'current_page_item';
                                echo '"><a href="'.get_term_link( $child_term->slug, 'job_cat' ).'">- '.$child_term->name.'</a></li>';
                         endforeach ;   

                    endif;

                endforeach;

                echo '</ul></li>';
    endif;

    // By Date
    if ( $datepage = JR_Date_Archive_Page::get_id() ) :
                $datepagelink = get_permalink($datepage);
                echo '<li><a class="top" href="#open">'.__('Date posted', APP_TD).'</a> <ul>';
                echo '<li><a href="'.add_query_arg( array( 'show' => 'today', 'jobs_by_date' => '1' ), $datepagelink).'">'.__('Today',APP_TD).'</a></li>';
                echo '<li><a href="'.add_query_arg( array( 'show' => 'week', 'jobs_by_date' => '1' ), $datepagelink).'">'.__('This Week',APP_TD).'</a></li>';
                echo '<li><a href="'.add_query_arg( array( 'show' => 'lsstweek', 'jobs_by_date' => '1' ), $datepagelink).'">'.__('Last Week',APP_TD).'</a></li>';
                echo '<li><a href="'.add_query_arg( array( 'show' => 'month', 'jobs_by_date' => '1' ), $datepagelink).'">'.__('This Month',APP_TD).'</a></li>';
                echo '</ul></li>';
    endif;
    ?>

    <?php jr_sidebar_nav_browseby(); ?>

</ul>
</div></div>
<div id="tags" class="tabbed_section"><div class="contents">
<?php
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'parent'             => 0,
        'hide_empty'         => (int)get_option('jr_show_empty_categories')
    );
    $terms = get_terms( 'job_tag',  apply_filters('jr_nav_job_tag', $args) );
    if ($terms) :
        echo '<ul class="job_tags">';

        foreach($terms as $term)
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( (int)$term->term_id, 'job_tag' ).'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';

        echo '</ul>';
    endif;
?>
</div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        jQuery('ul.widgets li.widget.widget-nav div ul li ul, ul.widgets li.widget.widget-nav div').hide();
        jQuery('.widget-nav div.tabbed_section:eq(0), .widget-nav div.tabbed_section:eq(0) .contents').show();
        jQuery('.widget-nav ul.display_section li:eq(0)').addClass('active');

        // Tabs
        jQuery('.widget-nav ul.display_section li a').click(function(){

            jQuery('.widget-nav div.tabbed_section .contents').fadeOut();
            jQuery('.widget-nav div.tabbed_section').hide();

            jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).show();
            jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href') + ' .contents').fadeIn();

            jQuery('.widget-nav ul.display_section li').removeClass('active');
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');

            return false;
        });

        // Sliding
        jQuery('ul.widgets li.widget.widget-nav div ul li a.top').click(function(){
            jQuery(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle();
        });

    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Thank you
Kind Regards

Comment: lol, nothing related to php at all. All u need is just javascript

Comment: thanks, which bit of Javascript please ?

Comment: at the end of the code u insert above. not sure but it toggle by clicking. try adding display:block to ul tag you want to show. at least it works in inspect element

Comment: I added the display:block to the UL tag, however the toggle boxes wont close with the display:block tag.   Any other ideas ? thanks